# Javac. Is there any shortcut to specify classpath in command line?

Tags: javac

THis is the usual way of compiling using `javac`

```
javac .;C:Users\xxx\ . . ; another jar; another jar . . . ; MyTest.java
```

Is there any way to put the list of references in an external `xml`, the same way Eclipse does `.classpath`     , and refer to this  file rather than list all the external jars in `-classpath` cmd?

Comment: Did you try running `javac -help`? That will tell you what options are available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a script instead of retyping this command line each time.  Another option is the [CLASSPATH](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) environment variable but you'll need to be careful not to set it globally (the doc specifically recommends using `-cp` instead of the environment variable).

You could write your own launcher that takes an XML file, converts it into a classpath string, and then launches java with the correct classpath argument.